# how to reset PHPSESSID cookie for different applications hosted on the same server

Tags: php, session-cookies

I have two applications Aand B hosted on the same server. In fact, B is a sub-application to A, housed within a subdir of A.

While the master (A) application uses default php session implementation, B implements session in database. An FYI.

When I access application B in a new browser or before having accessed A, it's cookies are set just fine.

However when I first access A, a PHPSESSID cookie is set. Now when I access B, cookies for B doesn't get set.

I am clueless as to why the PHPSESSID cookie set by A doesn't let B set any of it's cookies. The reverse is not true.

Comment: Can you comment on the domains used for apps A and B and the domains on which the session cookies are set?

Answer (score 1):

The cookies are conflicting because they are by default set on the full domain, with path `/`. As such there will be precedence when 2 applications both try to start a session. You can use [`session_set_cookie_params()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-set-cookie-params.php) to override the default path, and as such remove the conflict. You will most probably need to manually remove any 'old' cookies in your browser though afterwards as they will keep conflicting until expired otherwise.

Comment: I do notice that app A sets its cookies for path 'A' while B cookies path defaults to root. Need to check if confining app B cookies to path 'B' helps.
Question is: Is A getting precedence because it is setting it's cookie at a non-root path?

Comment: It most definitely will  :)   The default path could be set correctly by the application you installed, some 'common' apps set it to the root install path of the application internally.

Comment: I think I am getting closer!
Now, if I detect A's cookie at path say /A/, I want to set B's cookie at path /A/B/.
Isn't happening. setcookie returns false.
</br> Please note that the apps cookies do not share same names.

Comment: Huh, are you saying app B is installed in a subfolder of app A? If so you cannot fix this in the cookie paths, you'll need to change the name of the cookie as a whole with session_name (http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.session-name.php). Good thing is that it'll fix all your issues by definition if you do it that way.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, this dirty fix worked for the problem.

```
unset($_COOKIE[session_name()]);
session_destroy();
session_start();
```

I call it dirty fix because you probably cannot afford to unset and destroy session across your application. But mine was needed only on the authentication module (one place) and I am fine.